# .htaccess with multiple parameters

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess-File:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)?$ index.php?parent=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

It rewrites urls like `mypage.com/about` corretly to `mypage.com/index.php?page=about`.

When I call `mypage.com/work/project` it should connect me to `mypage.com/index.php?parent=work&page=project` but it doesn't works.
If I call `mypage.com/index.php?parent=work&page=project` directly, the site will be loaded without any problem. I can echo the GET-parameters, and they are in both way the same.

With these GET-parameters I load the content of page (jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var page = '<?php echo $page; ?>';
   var parent = '<?php echo $parent; ?>';
    if (page == "") {
     $("section").load("view/home.php article");
    } else {
     if (parent == "") {
      $("section").load("view/" + page + ".php article");
     } else {
      $("section").load("view/" + parent + "/" + page + ".php article");
     }
    }
   });
</script>
```

What did I wrong? Can someone help me out there?

Answer (score 1):

Change your .htaccess to

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*?)/([^/]+?)/?$ index.php?parent=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note that this would redirect `mypage.com/work/` to `mypage.com/index.php?page=work`. Change `+?` to `*?` if you want this also to redirect to `mypage.com/index.php?parent=work&page=`.

Comment: Hi & thanks for your answer. Still the same error - the content and the css will not be loaded.

Comment: Ah, misread your question. Just let me know: do you want `mypage.com/work/` (ends in a slash) to go to `?parent=work&page=` or `?page=work`?

Comment: Don't work either. If i use my .htaccess and want to call the url `mypage.com/work/` (with end slash) - the content of the page + the css will not be loaded, without end slash it works. With your code `mypage.com/work/project` will not fully directed to `mypage.com?parent=work&page=project` - i can echo the GET-parameters, but for any reason the content and the css are lost.

Comment: Maybe I do something wrong. I tried it with your .htaccess, but still the same error - I can't call the page with end-slash and also not "sub-pages"

Comment: It redirects me to `http://localhost/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/yanu/index.php?parent=work&page=flashcards` and throws an error. Only `http://localhost/yanu/index.php?parent=work&page=flashcards` works.

Comment: Add a leading slash to your rules: "/index.php" or "/yanu/index.php"

Comment: Finally i got it, I had to change all relative parameters to absolute parameters. It works, but it isn't really nice.

Comment: Can you elaborate on relative parameters? I might learn from your experience too. :)